# How do i send a user inputted int to my constructor (Java)

Tags: java

Hi so i am a really big noob at java, and i cant seem to be able to send an inputted int to my constructor.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    EasyReader d = new EasyReader();
    System.out.println("How many numbers are in your array?");
    int num = d.readInt();
}
```

and i want to send num to my constructor

```
public QuizScore(int num)
{
    for(int i=1;i<=num;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter in your scores: ");
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me out, that would be awesome, thanks guys

Comment: add next line to `main()` : `new QuizScore(num);`

Comment: Even after you pass the num, all your program is going to do is print "Enter in your scores: " a gillion times.

Comment: yah. how do i fix that? i keep trying to make an array for it to read into, but it wont work

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    EasyReader d = new EasyReader();
    System.out.println("How many numbers are in your array?");
    int num = d.readInt();
    new QuizScore(num);
}
```

Also you can read more about [constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).